# How do I stop immortal / immortalctl process?

Tags: command-line, restart, aws

This is driving me nuts!

I've been bombarding immortal to stop a process so I can update it, but it... won't stop... That process is immortal (pun intended)!

I'm trying to stop a .NET Core MVC application:

I've tried:

- `immortalctl stop <process-name>`
- `immortalctl stop <process-id>`
- `sudo immortalctl stop <process-name>`
- `sudo immortalctl stop <process-id>`
- `sudo immortalctl -k <process-id>`
- `sudo immortalctl -k <process-name>`
- `immortalctl -k <process-id>`
- `immortalctl -k <process-name>`
- `set IMMORTAL_EXIT=exit sudo immortalctl exit run`
- `sudo IMMORTAL_EXIT=exit immortalctl exit run`
  (Where run is the process name - see pictures).
- `sudo immortalctl halt "*"` And it comes back to life in about 5 seconds.

Here are the docs:
https://immortal.run/post/immortalctl/

Here's the current terminal:

[image: enter code here]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop/start/restart all depends on how you started the process if using [immortaldir](https://immortal.run/post/immortaldir/) the easy way is just to remove the `run.yml` or rename it to `run.yml-off` from the directory that you passed as an argument or  defined when calling `immortaldir` (probably `/etc/immortal`) check [How to install & setup](https://immortal.run/post/how-to-install/) for more details

If you ran the process using your `$USER` (not root), you could remove the `$HOME/.immortal` directory (this will stop other processes as well)

To manage the process you then can use [`immortalctl`](https://immortal.run/post/immortalctl/), in your case the name of your process is `run` therefore if you want to stop it just need to do:

```
# immortalctl stop run
```

or

```
$ sudo immortalctl stop run
```

In this case, `run` is the name of your service and also the name of your service config, probably located in `/etc/immortal/run.yml`

Keep in mind that `immortal` will do its best to keep your process up and running forever, if you are using:

```
# immortalctl  -k run
```

This will only send a kill signal to your process, but `immortal` will bring it up again, you may have already noticed that the PID changes.

When using `immortaldir` the options `exit` or `halt` will behave more like a restart, they indeed are exiting or halting (stopping and exiting the supervisor) but `immortaldir` will bring your application up again since the idea is to keep your application always running.

For more examples check: https://immortal.run/post/examples/

Answer (score 2):

This is such an unpredicted method:

1. Get the process of the IDs by doing `sudo immortalctl`, `immortalctl` (without sudo). Both throw different results.
2. Then do `immortalctl exit <pid-of-sudo-immortalctl>`.

This should stop it.

Also look in:

Comment: This isn't working -_-. I'm opening a GitHub issue

Comment: https://github.com/immortal/immortal/issues/44#issuecomment-436243276

Answer (score -1):

try `killall immortal` it ended the pid.